# How do I record the output from AVAudioEngine to an AAC file?

Tags: swift, audio, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder, avaudioengine

I have an app that plays recorded audio with effects. I would like to allow the users to share the result. I use `AVAudioEngine` with various `AVAudioUnit` nodes to create the effects.

**My question is**: how do I generate a file with the audio engine output? Is there a way to simply connect an `AVAudioRecorder` directly to the `AVAudioEngine's` implicit output node? Or do I have to install a tap on the mixer and write the file myself? And if so, how do I do that and get a `.aac` file in the end?

Further, ideally I would like to do this WITHOUT playing the audio - so the file would be created when the user chooses to share, in the background. Is there any way to do this? It seems like there should be a way...

I'd like to clarify: I'm looking for a solution using Swift and AVFoundation.

thanks!